# Create a new thread only when a previous one finished

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am working on a system with 4 cores. My code can be split up into parts that each work independently, but that require a significant amount of memory.

Is it possible to make my system wait for a thread to finish before creating a new one, such that I only have 4 threads running simultaneously, while still using all my cores completely?

Comment: To add to jsantander's answer: if you're beginner with coding and C++ libraries and if you don't mind using big library and different IDE, I would suggest to look at Qt ( http://qt-project.org/ ) library - it contains quite nice thread, mutex and wait condition classes (+ lot's of other stuff). I think it's good place to start with threads...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a queue where you post the requests.

Each request object with an execute method that encapsulates the work to do.

You launch the (four) threads at start up.

The threads run in a infinite loop (or until some indication is received that the thread must end), waiting for requests to come up in the queue and executing them.

Waiting can be done either by:

- Implementing a condition/signal mechanism (that will lock waiting until the it receives a signal when a new request is posted).
- Simply sleeping a short while

... in any case do not spin blindly in the loop

You need some mutex protecting the request queue... because it is memory shared by all threads.

---

Edit: Some pseudocode to help in understanding.

a) On initialization.

```
spawn 4 threads (all running mainThread())
```

b) On mainThread()

```
while(main program is running)         
    poll queue // shared by all threads        
    retrieve first Request object from queue.
    invoke execute method of Request object
    sleep some time (10 ms) // or use a condition/signal
end loop
```

As you can see the thread does not concern on the state of other threads, it just go to pick up some job, execute and come back for more.

You ensure that there's no more than 4 jobs running simultaneously at any time, because you only have 4 threads.

c) You have a Request class:

```
class Request {
public:
     virtual ~Request() { }
     virtual void execute() =0;
};
```

And one or more child classes:

```
class ThingToDoOfType1: public Request {
public:
    void execute() {
       // whatever means the "thing to do of type 1"
    }
}
```

Again the Request do not concern about the state of other requests... if they need to concern... then it becomes slightly more difficult.

d) Finally you need somewhere to insert Requests of the different types in the queue.
They can be inserted....

- All in one go. The threads will be picking one by one, with at most 4 executing at a time.
- Upon user requests or received from the network

An example could be in the initialization:

```
spawn 4 threads (all running maintThread())
Insert 1000 Requests of Type1, Type2 and Type 3.
```

The 1000 requests will be added two the queue from where it will be taken each time a thread finishes processing the previous request.

Comment: +1. But really, really don't use an infinite loop checking the queue each iteration, use the suggested wait/stop condition. (Writing this because answer does not discourage from using the infinite loop - I would suggest to add that...)

Comment: @Laethnes Actually my sentence was referring to how to stop at program end. I've clarified and added some notes on how to wait for new requests and warning against running on empty :D

Comment: I think I get it, but how do I check how many threads are running?

Comment: If this is windows, you can use CreateThread to create the threads, and WaitForSingleObject to wait for the threads to terminate. A more generic solution would be to create 4 threads, then use a messaging interface to coordinate the threads. There would be message used to start a sequence and a message from the thread when it completes a sequence. I use both mutex (for onwership) and semaphores (for pending message count) in the messaging systems I've coded. Windows has a WaitForMultipleObjects which can be used for an atomic wait for mutex + semaphore count != 0.

Comment: I mean that inside the loop, I need to check if a thread finished, before I start a new one. I'm not on Windows unfortunately.

Comment: @jsantander In that case, I apologize.

Comment: @Laethnes never mind, it certainly helped improving the answer.

Comment: @RobVerheyen Added some pseudo code to help in understanding. Note that this way the execution (where and when, i.e. the threads) is decoupled from what is executed (the `execute()` method)

Comment: @RobVerheyen I also wrote an example. It's long only because of explanation comments: http://pastebin.com/7KYbGumE

Comment: @RobVerheyen Btw.: our approach (mine and jsantander's - both are more-or-less the same) has an advantage when compared with destroying and creating threads - it's little faster, because operations (of destroying and creating) are quite expensive. If your task takes a lot of time, it's negligible, but sill...

Comment: Thanks for the pseudocode example! This helps a lot.

Comment: @RobVerheyen Btw. I finally realized what might be your problem - your problem generates a lots of sub-tasks and you want to generate one after another when some thread finishes, right? In that case, our answer is not quite complete, so here is updated example - http://pastebin.com/8QuWmiug - here the main thread is waiting until working threads removes all tasks from the queue so you can generate new one and add to the queue.

Comment: Going through your example made me realize how crap I am at properly writing C++ code. Anyway, I made a solution that is very similar to yours, but (for me) simpler to implement. All the tasks my threads have to perform are the same function with some different vector<int> as argument (called searchDim in the upcoming example). I wrote the following: http://pastebin.com/SyBR4HSY - If I understood your example right, this should do the same thing. It seems to be working at least. Thanks very much for all the effort you put into this answer!

Comment: @RobVerheyen Not sure whether the last comment of yours was directed on me or jsantander, but generally: yes, yours code looks like our suggestion (just without wait condition, which is not needed if you create all data to be processed beforehand) so I think yes, you understood our point correctly. About writing clean code: that is our never-ending task - to learn to write better and better code. Performance note: when you're getting data from queue, whole vector is copied which is really bad if the vector contains lots of data (like thousands or more) because each end every time...

Comment: @RobVerheyen ...new array is allocated and data copied which is expensive and not needed. I would suggest to use pointers (with some smart pointer) or some vector class implementing copy-on-write or which shares the data. But if your vector is small, I would guess it's premature optimization. But this is really just side-note. (Regrettably, AFAIK, in STL there is no such vector (with shared data or copy-on-write)...)

Answer (score 0):

Let the main thread create a thread only when the count is less than 4. Whenever a thread is closed, this count can be decremented and if a new thread is spanned count can be incremented. Make sure that count is mutex protected.